# Simple Addon: works with jpm run but not after installing the xpi:

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-addons

following the [Tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) i made an addon which is working with "jpm run" but not after installing the xpi file. I read the [issue197](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/197) but thats for "icons". The AddOn is shown correctly both ways.

But the clickEvent only works with "jpm run".

Function of the AddOn:
clicking in the frame.html runs the javascript

```
function FrameClick(){  
        window.parent.postMessage("Frame is clicked","*");  
}
```

The index.js should then open a Panel.

My code in index.js:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var mypanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("panel.js")
});

var { Frame } = require("sdk/ui/frame");
var frame = new Frame({                         
    url: "./frame.html"}
);

var { Toolbar } = require("sdk/ui/toolbar");
var toolbar = Toolbar({ 
  name: "toolbar",
  title: "Toolbar",
  items: [frame]
});

frame.on("message",MessageFromFrame)

function MessageFromFrame(e){
    console.log("MessageFromFrame: "+e);
    mypanel.show({position: {top:10,left:10}});
}

mypanel.on("show", function() {
    mypanel.port.emit("show",ShowFromMyPanel); 
});

function ShowFromMyPanel(e){
    console.log("ShowFromMyPanel: "+e); 
}
```

The data structure is:

```
myaddon
 index.js
 package.json
myaddon/data
 frame.html
 frame.js
 panel.html
```

Any suggestions where to look for the error?
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Were you able to figure out what was up?

Comment: Have you tried turning off firefox's private mode? That was an issue for me - even though I don't understand why my add-on shouldn't work during private mode.